# Android dynamic variable for drawable resource

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap

Hi I have a problem for my coding, how can I do this:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable."some string");
```

I'm using:

`getResources().getIdentifier(img, "drawable", context.getPackageName())`,

then it's showing:

> error cannot resolve method decodeResource(int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you can't do it that way, because "R.drawable.XXXXX" is an int that is generated at compile time.  I would recommend making a custom enum that associates the int with the string and provides a method to return one given the other.  For example:

```
public enum DrawableEnum {
    STRING_ONE("some string", R.drawable.some_string),
    STRING_TWO("another string", R.drawable.some_other_string),
    STRING_THREE("third string", R.drawable.string_three);

    private final String string;
    private final int resId;

    DrawableEnum(String string, int resId) {
        this.string = string;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    int getResId() {
        return resId;
    }

    String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    int getResIdFromString(String string) {
        for(DrawableEnum item : DrawableEnum.values()) {
            if(item.getString().equals(string)) {
                return item.getResId();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
int resId = DrawableEnum.getResIdFromString("some string");
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
```

Comment: STRING_ONE("some string", R.drawable.some_string),
    STRING_TWO("another string", R.drawable.some_other_string),
    STRING_THREE("third string", R.drawable.string_three); what does this 3 line means?

Comment: STRING_ONE, STRING_TWO, STRING_THREE is for what?

Comment: Those are the enums that would map the string name you want to reference to its actual R resource ID.  You will have to define each mapping that way.

Comment: STRING_ONE("background", R.drawable.background); example like this? if I have 10 images then I need to increase the STRING_NUM also?

Comment: Ok, but I still not understand what is the STRING_NUM? it's a variable?

Comment: It's like a variable, but is technically the constant that represents the particular DrawableEnum. It can be named whatever you want, but each one has to be different.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to get resource id with the following code:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("some_string", "drawable", getPackageName());
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
```

Comment: Tried oredi, this 1 failed